# Magento 2.3.2 Unable to send the cookie. Size of 'mage-messages' is 4191 bytes

Tags: cookie, magento2.3.2

Last two days suddenly my logs are filled with this in Magento 2.3.2:

```
report.ERROR: Unable to send the cookie. Size of 'mage-messages' is 4191 bytes.
```

> In Stores>Configuration>General>Web

**My Default Cookie Settings are:**

> Cookie Lifetime: 3600(default)
>
> Cookie Path:
>
> Cookie Domain:
>
> Use Http only: Yes
>
> Cookie Restriction Mode: No

Does anybody have this issue?
Can't find something related when I searched about

Comment: Any luck on your side finding anything about it?

Comment: @ChaosTheoryV2X No sorry...

Comment: @G.G Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

The error is because in the cookie mage-messages exists exception trace.
Try to increase the value of `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager::MAX_COOKIE_SIZE = 40960;`
And see in a browser response header value for set-cookie: mage-messages

Comment: This cookie checker is so ghetto, why not let the browser just tell you if you've overloaded its cookie allocations lol.

Comment: You shouldn't increase the value as most browsers in 2021 have a limit of 4096 bytes for the cookie, which means that you get problems with the browser once you increase this value, see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178194(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#cookie-limitations

Answer (score 4):

Something is being set in the cookie that exceeds the size. This probably isn't expected behavior. To see what is being set, open `vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php` and change line 214-225 to;

```
if ($sizeOfCookie > static::MAX_COOKIE_SIZE) {
    throw new CookieSizeLimitReachedException(
        new Phrase(
            'Unable to send the cookie. Size of \'%name\' is %size bytes, value is %value',
            [
                'name' => $name,
                'size' => $sizeOfCookie,
                'value' => $value
            ]
        )
    );
}
```

The error will now show what the contents of the to-be-set cookie would be.

Comment: thanks it helps to identify from where issue is coming

Answer (score 1):

**MDVA-41215** patch should resolve your issue: [MDVA-41215: Users get 500 error after setting "mage-messages" cookie](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/4417378995853-MDVA-41215-Users-get-500-error-after-setting-mage-messages-cookie)